# Problems with nested gridview parent row color

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to set the rows colours in the parent grid view base on the data. For example in the coding, if the currency is USD then set the row to chocolate colour else set it to red but instead my program shows that its all in red even though there is currency USD data in the gridview.

heres my code behind,

```
Protected Sub gvUserInfo_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False
        Dim currency As String = e.Row.Cells(3).Text
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HedgingTestConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
            For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
                If currency = "USD" Then
                    cell.ForeColor = Color.Chocolate
                Else
                    cell.BackColor = Color.Red
                    Label1.Text = e.Row.Cells(3).Text
                End If
            Next
            con.Open()
            Dim gv As GridView = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("gvChildGrid"), GridView)
            Dim ref As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells(1).Text)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from TT where Reference_NO=" & ref, con)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)

            con.Close()
            gv.DataSource = ds
            gv.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Below is my gridview code,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Hedging_ID,CCY"        HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Medium" HeaderStyle-BackColor="SeaGreen" OnRowDataBound="gvUserInfo_RowDataBound" width="100%"  
        HorizontalAlign="Center" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("ref_ID")%>');">
            <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("ref_ID")%>" border="0" src="plus.png" />
            </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="20px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:BoundField DataField="ref_ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ref_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Bank_Name" HeaderText="Bank" SortExpression="Bank_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CCY" HeaderText="Currency" SortExpression="CCY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ref_Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Contract Date" SortExpression="Ref_Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ref_End_Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Maturity Date" SortExpression="Ref_End_Date" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="100%">
            <div id="div<%# Eval("Hedging_ID")%>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderStyle="Double"  BorderColor="#df5015" GridLines="None" Width="700px" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#E1E1E1" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Invoice_Number" HeaderText="Invoice Number" SortExpression="Invoice_Number" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Payment_Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Payment Date" SortExpression="Payment_Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Payment_Amount" DataFormatString="{0:c2}" HeaderText="Payment Amount" SortExpression="Payment_Amount" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>


<HeaderStyle BackColor="SeaGreen" Font-Size="Medium"></HeaderStyle>


<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></RowStyle>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition like this

```
            If currency = "USD" Then
                cell.BackColor= Color.Chocolate
            Else
                cell.BackColor = Color.Red
                Label1.Text = e.Row.Cells(3).Text
            End If
```

May be thats because you have put "ForeColor"